# Chrome desktop notification for dynamic site update when chrome runs in background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've created a bookmark extension for community website, which host posts, I need to have desktop notification of new posts in community site. chrome runs on background, but no tabs will be opened, unless notified by desktop notification.

Idea is to send a message from background page to content script for regular interval and get updates on the post and display a desktop notification, thereby user opens the update on seeing notification.

Query: 
How to access the DOM of website (when chrome is running in background), hiding extraction process from the user eye.

Thanks !!

EDIT

```
var statone;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.dsswym.3ds.com/", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200) {
    setTimeout(function(){ //wait for the webpage loading 
        statone = $('#widgetPanel-7qrSN8CAwqKk0DP2_GQK').text();
        console.log(statone);
        alert(statone); 
     }, 10000);
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

I'm not able to get text values on above code, instead my alert box is empty. Source site doesn't provide xml or Json file, just i need to extract the first content or update on the site.

Comment: "*How to access the DOM of website (when chrome is running in background)*" -- [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)? See also http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html

Comment: @apsillers: Thanks !, I'm working on it. Will get back on doubts if any.

Comment: @apsillers: I tried extracting the DOM using the code i've updated in the query section. No luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the *response* from the `XMLHttpRequest`. Doing an `XMLHttpRequest` request doesn't load the request resource into the page.

In jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
$.get("https://www.dsswym.3ds.com/", function(data) {
        // load response text into a new page element
        var fakePage = document.createElement("html");
        fakePage.innerHTML = data;

        // find the desired element within the new page element
        var statone = $(fakePage).find('#widgetPanel-7qrSN8CAwqKk0DP2_GQK').text();
        console.log(statone);
    }
});
```

This stores the result of the Ajax fetch into the `innerHTML` of a new `<html>` element, which cases the text to be parsed into a new DOM. We then use jQuery's `.find` method to get the element we need out of that DOM.

Comment: I got the page content, since the page is driven by javascript (dynamic page), i'm unable to get the vital elements i.e. few element are missing in the data content of the function. Any idea how to get complete element of the webpage.